# What funding is available for undergraduate research in Japan?

Tags: funding, research-undergraduate, student-exchange, japan

I wish to go to Japan for a semester-long research internship in the field of robotics. I am a Canadian citizen.

However, I am having a hard time finding what funding I can actually apply for.

I know the JSPS fellowships are out of question as they only apply to postdocs.
MEXT fellowships are out as well because they are only for a full 5 years.

**What funding is available for undergraduate research in japan?**

Comment: MEXT has short term programs too: http://www.mext.go.jp/english/highered/1303739.htm  You might also check with your study abroad office and professors in your field.  It helps if you have some contact over there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most if not all scholarships for studying in Japan are listed in the ["Scholarship for International Students in Japan"](http://www.jasso.go.jp/en/study_j/scholarships/brochure.html) brochure published by the Japan Student Services Oganization (JASSO). Most of them are aimed at students enrolled in a degree program at a Japanese university, however.

For a short-term visit, there is in particular the [Student Exchange Support Program](http://www.jasso.go.jp/en/study_j/scholarships/scholarship/short_term.html) scholarship by JASSO (which I have received in the past). You apply for it through your host university, so do ask them about it if they have not mentioned it to you. Note that the amount is "only" 80,000 JPY per month, which is certainly not enough to live on: the goal is to help cover your costs, not to cover them fully.

Answer (score 3):

@Kayan and @fkraiem have provided links for general (undergraduate) fellowships in Japan. You'll note that most provide tuition and a living stipend (as well as airfare / language training in some cases).

What these fellowships do not provide is **research funding** -- if by this you mean equipment and supply costs. They will not provide funds if you want to build a robot, run experiments, or even to buy a laptop/Raspberry PI.

This is because research grants for equipment purchases go to university professor- and researcher-run labs. If you want to do research in robotics, you should write to professors/researchers and ask them if you can study in their lab for a year under the various scholarship/fellowship programs listed by the other respondents.

Comment: Thank you for the precision, I did indeed mean the living stipend part of research funding.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few funding sources may help you to study in Japan.

**Scholarships for International Students in Japan:**
http://www.jasso.go.jp/en/study_j/scholarships/scholarship/index.html

**Japanese Government (Monbukagakusho) Scholarship:**
http://www.studyjapan.go.jp/en/toj/toj0302e.html

**Embassies, Consulates, Permanent Missions Overseas:**
http://www.mofa.go.jp/about/emb_cons/over/index.html

**Here is another one especially for women:**
http://www.cwaj.org/Scholarship/njg.html

Comment: Sadly the one for women will have to go to someone else.

Comment: That last one is irrelevant also because it requires being enrolled in a graduate degree program in Japan.

Comment: And the MEXT scholarships, for the same reason. Here's a -1.